# Como colocar o numero da página a ser impressa com CSS no @media print

Tags: html, css, paginação, media-queries

Quero colocar o número da página quando o usuário quiser imprimir minha página web. Por exemplo, quando ele for imprimir minha página, e ela for quebrada em duas, quero que apareça "página 01/02" e "02/02" nas páginas, utilizando CSS.

Comment: Se ainda estiver interessado, recomendo dar uma olhada na edição que eu fiz. Acho que atende ao seu pedido.

Answer (score 4):

Olá!

Você já deve ter pesquisado o suficiente e encontrado os dois métodos atualmente falhos que estão em todos os cantos da web:

1. O método usando `@page` com `bottom-right`. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109932)
2. O método por footer fixado. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651296)

Após muito quebrar a cabeça, eu acho que consegui vir com algo viável que ainda está para ser testado em todos os browsers. (Por enquanto posso garantir que funcionou no Chrome.)

Basicamente, misturando um pouco de cada técnica, eu pude criar essa forma que replica um `h3` em `position: absolute` e sempre joga a página pra `100vh` a menos na visão de impressão. (Indo assim pro fundo da página).

A regra que criei para numeração de página, nesse caso, podendo ser adaptado para a situação de cada um, foi que criasse uma numeração de página para cada 10 `p`s presentes no texto, que foi a média do exemplo. Desse jeito ele não numera a mais nem a menos.

Infelizmente, dessa forma não é possível botar o total de páginas, pois o que eu fiz foi simular um total de páginas baseado em número de parágrafos.

Deixo aqui o trabalho feito: [JSFiddle - Sem Total de Páginas](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/zscoopoc)

### EDIT

Segue uma nova versão capaz de numerar o **total de páginas**: [JSFiddle - Com Total de Páginas](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/9u4e8ajx/)

Valeu!

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

eu faço assim

```
<style>
      #rodape::after { content: '| Página ' counter(page); }
      #rodape {
        /* string-set: footing content(); */
        running: footer;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0;
        right: 10px;
        height: 12px;

        /** Extra personal styles **/
        color: black;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 12px;
        padding: 2em auto 0;
        max-width: 767px;
      }
      @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
              margin: 1.5cm 1cm 1.2cm;
        counter-increment: page;
         }
</style>

      <div id="rodape">
</div>
```